# Google App Engine, GData & Picasa

Tags: google-app-engine, gdata-api, picasa

Is there more comprehensive sample of creating **Google App Engine** App using **GData Python Library** to interact with **Picasa Web Album**, other than google guide from GAE here: http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html

Comment: That looks pretty comprehensive! If there's something missing, you'll need to tell us what.

Comment: Sorry Nick, i'm just a newbie on GAE. The getting started part of the guide of installing gdata. It is work on local Phyton SDK as well? Is it just copying the gdata & atom folder to app directory? The other part is no explanation about single user auth. parameter of gd_client.source = 'exampleCo-exampleApp-1', is this the GAE app id? My code doesn't really work, wether in the local SDK or at appspot. Thanks for the guide, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting started with GAE and GData, you can take a look at:
http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/python/retrieving_gdata_feeds.html

You should be able to update the samples code there to use PhotosService instead of DocClient.